# How to remove unused libraries from an external library folder in project view inside android studio?

Tags: android, android-studio

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fW8Ts.png)[image: Screenshot]

I compiled different versions of same dependency, but now dependencies only consist of the latest version. These previous libraries do not have any deleting option.

A related question: Will removing these extra libraries reduce the apk size?

Comment: You may want to explain more about the issue so someone may be able to help you out. See [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: don't need to.Gradle auto use latest version

Answer (score 0):

1. goto settings.gardle
2. remove library name like this

   include ':app', ':DialogLib', ':librestreaming'

   include ':app', ':DialogLib'
3. after remove library then click on sync now
4. now you can delete the folder of library